# SharePoint 2010 Site collection and subsite usage and last visits

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, web-analytics, site-usage, analytics

I am trying to figure out which are the most used and least used sites in a site collection and when was each of the site last visited.

From the analytics report I could only see the top used page and the total number of views.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods:

- Parse the IIS logs.

  If you want a repeatable process, you can develop
  a desktop application for parsing the IIS logs and install it at the
  server machine. Then every time you need a report of unused sites,
  all you need to do is running this application.
- Configure and view [audit log reports](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-audit-log-reports-4293e8d5-4e7d-4201-b8ac-c8e63a100131).

  Audit log reports can track users actions on the site. When users visit the site, they definitely will visit the specific content such as a home page. The View event is available for audit log reposts. Analyze this data to determine which site is most visited site and when user visited the site.
- Use code to get access date when users access the site, and add each access date into a list. Then you can filter and analysis the data of this list to get the last accessed date.